# Gravity simulation: Possible?

Tags: science-based, super-powers

I want to create a character with the ability to simulate an increase or decrease of gravities effect on an object or area. Is this possible?
Restrictions: Gravity will still work (I want to work around gravity, not destroy it)
No using acceleration or any direct force. (She's not a TK)
Beyond that, there are no restrictions (power is not an issue and other laws of physics can be bent)

Comment: All you have to do is ' shinra tensei '.

Comment: Check this page: http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Manipulation and see what you like the most.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the link, but it really only gave me applications of gravity manipulation, not methods.

Comment: There are no scientifically plausible methods to manipulate gravitation. Users of gravitational superpowers (at the link) use their powers in different ways, but as far as I know, none of them has any solid explanation regarding the nature of those powers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no know physics law to permit what you are looking for, much to the chagrin of those like me who read Ender's Game and fantasized about making the battle room a reality on Earth.

You would need to create a force on the object.

- If you could convince everything in the area to distribute lots of iron filings through their bodies, you could do this with magnetism... but it's really hard to do it without enough ferromagnetic material in your target.
- You can do a lot of interesting things with rotating frames creating centripetal accelerations, but that's not quite what you want.

If you have a great deal of control over the area *and* only need to do this for a short period of time, you could simply put everything on an elevator and accelerate it up or down.  There's no laws of physics that get in your way there, but you'll quickly reach speeds that are uncomfortable if you have to maintain this effect for a long time.

If you just need handwaving, you could consider using some of the "exotic" materials they use in some theories to make traversable wormholes.  These materials have really strange properties such as negative mass, and I think that means they would have negative gravitational forces as well.  That being said, they're called "exotic" because not only have we never seen any, there's no particular reason to believe they exist at all.  They're just interesting mathematical solutions to equations.